# Implicit none - Explicit type - Abstract interface - Error

Tags: types, fortran, implicit

The following Fortran Code:

```
module Mod
    implicit none

    TYPE derivedtype
        procedure(procInterface),POINTER,PASS::f
    END TYPE derivedtype

    ABSTRACT INTERFACE        
        subroutine procInterface(A)
            import derivedtype            
            implicit none
            class(derivedtype),intent(inout)::A
        end subroutine
    END INTERFACE

end module Mod
```

produces an error if compiled with ifort:

error #6404: This name does not have a type, and must have an explicit type.   [F]

Why? Is this a bug?

Comment: It refers to "procedure(procInterface),POINTER,PASS::f"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is propably a compiler short-coming. The Cray and IBM compilers can compile this specific module as well, as gfortran 4.6.1. Depending on what you want to achieve, you maybe could use generic type-bound procedures instead, however I am unsure, if this would be better supported by the Intel compiler.